# What is the main usage of index.d.ts in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have seen some projects declaring all the types in `index.d.ts`. So that the programmer do not need to explicitly import the type from other files.

```
import { TheType } from './somefile.ts'
```

Is that the correct usage of `index.d.ts` file? I'm not able to find anything in the official documentation.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`*.d.ts`  files are used to provide typescript type information about a module that's written in JavaScript, for example, underscore / lodash / aws-sdk.

This will allow you to use the javascript modules without the need to convert them to ts without getting any type of error on your code.

for example, if you have a folder myAwesomeLib, with index.js and index.d.ts files

on your code, you will be able to import the code with

```
import { SomeMethod } from './myAwesomeLib';
```

or

```
import { SomeMethod } from './myAwesomeLib/index';
```

your typescript will rely on the `.d.ts` file to find the correct types for the `SomeMethod`

**Edit**: More about Declaration files https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Comment: Thanks. If I can declare my interfaces in `index.ts`, why would I need `index.d.ts`?

Comment: If you have `index.ts` you  won't need the `index.d.ts`

Comment: so to use js files in ts file we can use index.d.ts. what is the difference between loading js files in angular.json scripts and accessing like  "declare var pluginName:any"  and index.d.ts

Comment: Not sure how angular.json would work, but `index.d.ts` is just to help you with `tsc`, you will still be able to use things the only difference is that `tsc` won't know anything about them. having a `.d.ts` file is probably the cleanest way to make it easy to use for `ts` code, a lot of modules (for example `aws-sdk`) have been adding that file

Comment: @dege I ended up here because I was trying to figure out how to contribute types to a JS package.  Been using TS for months, had no idea that a package written in TS doesn't need a declaration file!  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 4):

It's Similar to .h file in C
Or you may imagine an interface subsystem in any other language like java or php

The file contains function prototype (declaration & typing) of an underlying library

for reference on how to generate a .d.ts file from a library.js reefer
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html

Answer (score 0):

index = you guess it right
d = declaration
ts = typescript

A helper file if you will, it describes the types of functions, classes, variables, objects, exported by a module written in JavaScript. There s no logic, no code to be executed.

What is it used for?
To improve type safety in codes, provide intelli-sense(autocompletion), and we can also easily transition from JavaScript to TypeScript that way.

In short, it describes a shape of a module (a JavaScript file), used for type checking.