# what is the need of index.d.ts in angular? how it differs from "declare var pluginName:any"

Tags: angular, typescript

am developing the application in angular 6, I am given a task that i need to use npm modules which is developed in es6, so when we run build it will throw error in IE( caz webpack just merge all npm module into vendor.js and arrow functions not available in IE).

So what i did was i have taken out that files and transpiled into es5 and placed inside src folder then added in the angular.json to access in ts files and i used like

```
declare var pluginName:any
```

and it works fine.

I have seen other way that using index.d.ts it can be done?

is that like that? what is the need of that and how it loads js file in ts file?

any major difference ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the main usage of index.d.ts in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516394/what-is-the-main-usage-of-index-d-ts-in-typescript)

Comment: Ya i have seen that post, but my question is why instead of "declare var" we need to go for index.d.ts

Comment: Please check your question's title.

Comment: May this help you https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Comment: @gauti. The whole point of TypeScript is to have types. If all you have is variables of type àny`, the code is as unsafe, hard to maintain, hard to read as in JavaScript. The index.d.ts file provides the types of the variables, classes, interfaces provided by Angular.

Comment: The reason behind confusion is, when I transpiled es6 files from npm modules it has "module.export = plugin" at the end of file. 

so when i place it in src folder and load through angular.json script it shows error (module is undefined) in browser.

at the same time instead of loading it from angular.json, i placed inside folder with same module.exports along with index.ts file which has "module.export=pluginname". Now the js file doesn't show any error in browser.