# Missing constructor body inside Class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, constructor

I am reading type definition of react in [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts). Inside the code, I found inside class Component {} (in line 396), there is constructor without body as below (line 435 ):

```
constructor(props: Readonly<P>);
```

Why there is no implementation of constructor inside a class. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are reading index.d.ts

its only typescript definition for javascript implementation.

[read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516394/what-is-the-main-usage-of-index-d-ts-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks a lot, then where will be the actual implementation file?

Comment: d.ts can be generated from .ts with typescript compiler. or it is just written by another person for pure javascript file. so implementation will be in .js/ .ts, what you are reading is type definition for react library, so it will be https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react i guess

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js there is your component implementation

Comment: if you have installed react, you can go to node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js and there is exactly version what you are using

Answer (score 0):

Since React is what instantiates the class for you, the type definition is simply informing you of what would be passed to the constructor if you decided to provide one.

This is also useful because it instructs you how to call super(). If you were to create a constructor, you would need to pass the received props to super even if your class did not need them, e.g.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // your constructor logic here
}
```